# RecyclerView SnapHelper - how to change background of snapped and unsnapped items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm using recyclerview with horizontal LinearLayoutManager. I want to change recyclerview item color, when item is snapped in a middle.

So i used LinearSnapHelper.

At the moment, each items, which were previously snapped stays with snapped background color. So What i did, I made global variable snappedPosition and set it to 0, so first item of the recyclerview will be snapped by default.

Then I called that snappedPosition in onBindViewHolder of my adapter and changed color of item to default for every item in recyclerview except one with same position as position of snapped item. But at notifyItemChanged(position) ive got:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

code inside fragment:

```
val snapHelper: LinearSnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
var snappedPosition: Int = 0

        addressRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.address_recycler_view).apply {

            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter

        }

        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(addressRecyclerView)
        addressRecyclerView.onFlingListener = snapHelper
        itemOffsetDecoration = ItemOffsetDecoration(context, R.dimen.address_recyclerview_padding)
        addressRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemOffsetDecoration)

        addressRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    val centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(viewManager)
                    if (centerView != null) {

                        snappedPosition = addressRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(centerView)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

code inside onBindViewHolder

```
addressList[position].let {


                if (position == fragment.snappedPosition){
                    holder.itemViewLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.payment_button_active)
                    notifyItemChanged(position)
                } else {
                    holder.itemViewLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.payment_button_inactive)
                    notifyItemChanged(position)
                }

            }
```

What i want to achieve is similar to this image example:

[image]

Update: Code example for color change variant (still not working):

```
addressRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    val centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(addressRecyclerView.layoutManager)
                    if (centerView != null) {
                        for(item in 0 until addressRecyclerView.layoutManager.childCount){
                            val holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = addressRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(item)
                            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.payment_button_inactive)
                        }
                        centerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.payment_button_active)

                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: What happens if you just don't call `notifyItemChanged()`?

Comment: First item of recyclerview is permanently with snapped background and other items are with default one.

Comment: Why don't you change the color in the scroll listener? You know the snapped position there and you can avoid making changes in the view holder binding.

Comment: Tried this, but after second item ive got java.lang.IllegalStateException: addressRecyclerView.find…rForAdapterPosition(item) must not be null - code is above

Comment: You can't just do `centerView .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.payment_button_active)` in the scroll listener? That doesn't work?

Comment: it works like that. But i have to set previously selected background color to default. If i just do centerView.setbackgroundResource(active) as you said, it will change color of each recyclerviewItem which will be snapped to the center of the screen while scrolling. If you scroll and snap through each of recyclerview items. whole recyclerview ends up with selected background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following to track the current snapped view, set the appropriate background and clearing it upon movement of the `RecyclerView`. This avoids making modifications to the adapter.

```
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                View view = mSnapHelper.findSnapView(recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
                mLastSnappedView = view;
            } else if (mLastSnappedView != null) {
                mLastSnappedView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                mLastSnappedView = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        }
    });
```